# How to perform Mesh/Sort Elements for objects through Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I've many objects that i need to Sort its faces with the same criteria(As example according to **VIEW Z Axis**.
I do iterate through selected objects through:

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
```

but haven't succeeded performing the view dependant part.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do this without using bpy.ops?

Comment: No i don't, my question is all about the _bpy.ops.._part.

Comment: It will have to be written as an operator, so it can be run in the 3D viewport, else it will error(won't have a view to work with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your picture. I modified the Simple Operator template:

```
import bpy

def main(context):
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH': #make sure its a mesh
            context.scene.objects.active = obj
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.sort_elements(type='VIEW_ZAXIS') #this is what you're looking for
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Press spacebar in 3D viewport and type Simple Operator in the text field.

Comment: Just added (bpy.) at the beginning of the first line under (if obj.type...) Worked perfectly, seems my problem that i was trying to run the script from the text editor, while it must run through the view itself.Thanks a lot